# How to find relation correctly and their property?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have such a question:

$${A = \{1, 2, 3\}}$$
$${R \text{ on } P(A)}$$
$${\{3\} \subset a \cap b \leftrightarrow aRb}$$

Question is - if such relation is `symmetric`, `antisymmetric`, `transitive` or `reflexive`

So, as I far as I understand first of all we have a set `1, 2, 3`, so `P(A)` is

$${\{\{1\} \  \{2\} \  \{3\} \  \{1, 2\} \   \{1, 3\} \  \{2, 3\}  \ \{1, 2, 3\} \ \varnothing \}}$$

ok, so let's make a relation that fit to this condition

$${\{3\} \subset a \cap b \leftrightarrow aRb}$$

so,

$${R = \{\{1, 3\}  \ \{2, 3\} \ \{1, 2, 3\} \}}$$

and for know, when I know that `R` is I can say if this set is `symmetric`, `antisymmetric`, `transitive` or `reflexive`

1. Symmetric - no
2. antisymmetric - yes
3. transitive - no
4. reflexive - no

What is my question - I have just `antisymmetric` - yes, but as far as I know the right answer that just `symmetric` - yes, thus my logic isn't right. What is not right in this logic?

Comment: Since $\{3\} \subset a \cap b$, then $\{1,2,3\}R\{2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}R\{1,3\}$ but $\{1,3\} \not \sim  \{1,2\}$.

Comment: What you're written down is not $R$, since the elements of $R$ are pairs of subsets of $A$; for example $(\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\})\in R$.

Comment: @healynr But $\{2,3\}R\{1,3\}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Why? Isn't $\{2,3\} \cap \{1,3\} = \{3\}$ and $\subset$ indicates proper subset?

Comment: @healynr no, he means that in your first comment you wrote `but {1,3}≁{1,2}` , but should be written `But {2,3}R{1,3}`

Comment: @healynr: Unfortunately, the symbol $\subset$ is ambiguous, and far too many people use it to mean $\subseteqq$, so we can’t be sure which is meant here. However, the OP’s incorrect listing of $R$ does not include $\{3\}$, so it appears that the OP at least is interpreting it as proper subset.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh I see thank you.

Comment: Did you intend $p\subset q$ to mean $p\subseteq q$ or $p\subsetneq q \text{ ?} \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

A relation on the power set of $A$ should be represented by a set of ordered pairs of subsets of $A,$ not by a set of subsets of $A.$

$$
R = \left\{ \begin{array}{cccccccccc} \big(\{3\},\{3\}\big), \, \big(\{3\}, \{1,3\}\big), \, \big(\{1,3\},\{3\}\big),\\
\big(\{2,3\},\{3\}\big),\, \big(\{3\},\{2,3\}\big), \\
\big(\{3\},\{1,2,3,\}\big) , \big(\{1,2,3\},\{3\}\big), \\
\big(\{1,3\},\{1,3\}\big),\, \big(\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\big), \big(\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\big), \\
\big(\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\big),\,\big(\{1,2,3\},\{1,3\}\big), \\
\big( \{2,3\},\{2,3\}\big), \big(\{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\big),\, \big( \{1,2,3\}, \{2,3\}\big), \\
\big( \{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\big)  \end{array}  \right\}
$$
(At this point I'm not completely sure I didn't miss any.)

This relation is symmetric and transitive. It is not reflexive on the power set of $A=\{1,2,3,\}$ because, for example, it is not true that $\{1,2\} \mathbin{R} \{1,2\}.$

Comment: Can you explain to me why it is transitive? I thought $\{2,3\}$ did not relate to $\{1,3\}$ even though $\{2,3\}R\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}R\{1,3\}$.

Comment: @healynr : Why would you say it is not true that $\{2,3\} \mathbin{R} \{1,3\} \text{ ?}$ The set $\{3\}$ is a subset of both of them, and that was the definition.

Comment: I assumed that $\subset$ meant proper subset (as opposed to $\subseteq$) but apparently as @Brian M. Scott pointed out that is not always the case.

Comment: @healynr : If that means proper subset then it is still the case that $\{2,3\} \mathbin{R} \{1,3\}$ since $\{3\}$ is a proper subset of both.

Comment: but it isn't a proper subset of their intersection, is it? Isn't their intersection $\{3\}$?

Comment: @healynr : I see. In that case the answer would be different. However, the relation should still be represented by a set of ordered pairs of subsets of $\{1,2,3\}. \qquad$

Comment: I am afraid that it could be kind of misunderstanding, bacause in my case `P(A)` is - `{{1} {2} {3} {1,2} {1,3} {2,3} {1,2,3} ∅}`, this set has an 8 items, because that set A has 3 items, thus `P(A) = 2^3 = 8`. Thus it is not pair of pairs...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko : I didn't say it was a pair of pairs, but rather that it is a set of pairs.